# How to generalize a property of polynomials to a property of analytic functions?

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, analytic-functions

Let $A$ be a fixed real matrix such that $A$ can be written as $A = B + C$ for some $B, C$. Suppose that for any polynomial $f$ we have $f(A) = f(B) + f(C)$.

**When is it true that $g(A) = g(B) + g(C)$ when $g$ is not a polynomial but an analytic function?**

Writing $g = \lim_{n \to \infty} g_n$ with $g_n(x) = \sum_{k=0}^n \alpha_k  x^k$, I have that $g_n(A) = g_n(B) + g_n(C)$ for each $n$. Is this enough to  ascertain the same equality for $g$? Why or why not?

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Note we must require $f(0) = 0$ and $g(0) = 0$ in the definitions for this to make sense.  Otherwise the assumptions are contradictory (which I guess means the conclusion is valid, but only because it's vacuous)

Comment: Yes, I can see that now, thanks.

Comment: If you assume for _any_ polynomial $f$ that $f(A) = f(B) + f(C),$ then it also holds for $f(x) = 1.$  This immediately gives a contradiction in the form $1=2.$  If you just remove the constant polynomials, the contradiction still may be recovered, so the most natural fix is to assume $f(A) = f(B) + f(C)$ for all polynomials such that $f(0) = 0.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is true. If $g$ is analytic on $\mathbb C$ the it has an expanseion $g(z)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} a_nz^{n}$ valid for all $z$. This implies that $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} |a_n| R^{n}<\infty$ for all $R>0$. It follows that the series $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n M^{n}$ converges in the matrix norm for any $M$. So applying the hypothesis for the partial sums of $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} a_nz^{n}$ and taking limits yields the conclusion. [Note that $g(A),  g(B),g(C)$ are **defined** by taking limits of the partial sums of the corresponding series].

Comment: And when $g$ is not entire, I'm pretty sure $A = B\oplus C,$ so $\|A\| = \max(\|B\|, \|C\|)$ and it still works.